# Reading a specif line from a txt file in c++

Tags: c++, file, io

So, I've found the specific line of a file that I want to read, but what I've got isn't working:

```
    string str;
int target = 0;
ifstream record;

record.open("Record.txt");
target = std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(record), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n') - 8;
cout << target << endl;

for(int lineNum = 0; lineNum <= target; lineNum++)
{
    getline(record, str);
    if(lineNum == target)
    {
        cout <<"the id: "<< str << endl;
    }
}
```

In the above, I use std::count to count the lines of a file.  I know that I'll always want to read the eigth line from the bottom, so I set my target to that.  Next, I loop through each line up to target times, and do a check to see if i'm at the target line.  If so, then cout the line.

However, it's not giving me anything.  For a file with 22 lines, I get the following output:

```
14
the id:
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong or give me some hints?  Thanks!

Comment: What if the file you are reading has empty lines at the end?

Comment: Even after correcting the code you’re traversing the file twice. This is quite slow and unnecessary. Just have a buffer of the eight last read lines and once you hit EOF, retain only the first line of the buffer.

Comment: the way I'm creating the file, it never will :)

Answer (score 3):

The `record` stream will be `eof()` after the `std::count()` call but the code *never* checks the return value of `std::getline()` so is unaware that it is failing: **always check return value of read operations**. This means that `str` is never populated hence nothing is printed after the `"thid id: "` message.

You need to reset the stream or re-open it.

Comment: epic! Can't believe I forgot to reset the stream. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @SantasNotReal, if you don't want to re-read the file again, you can always use a `queue` of size 8. The logic you can use is to keep pushing lines to a `queue` till size is less than 8, otherwise pop and push. After reading the file once, your target line is at the top.

Comment: @Vikas For this project I'm not worried too much about efficiency for the moment as opposed to getting a working iteration.  And I know the file size will always be "relatively" small, but that is a great idea for increasing efficiency.  I'll definitely be doing this for the next iteration.